# How can i install HPLIP Missing Dependencies along with some brokern packages through terminal?

Tags: package-management, printing, dpkg, dependencies, hplip

I run a command " $ python install.py"

then the following message prompted on the screen:

```
MISSING DEPENDENCIES
--------------------
Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
cups-image           base                 REQUIRED            
sane-devel           scan                 REQUIRED            
cups-devel           base                 REQUIRED
```

Then I pressed yes to allow automatically install the missing dependencies which is as below - it prompted with an error :

```
DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcupsimage2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #1...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcupsimage2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #2...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcupsimage2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #3...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcupsimage2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s) (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ?
```

How can I come over with this problem ? Please help to resolve this problem.

when I run command I get following message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using 
the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
libcupsimage2-dev : Depends: libcups2-dev (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not
going to be installed 
Depends: libtiff-dev E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken  packages. –
```

Comment: did you try to resolve the dependencies yourself with sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2-dev

Comment: yes i did but it did not work either.

Comment: Please edit your post rather than providing bits and pieces of information in comments.